# Parsing Bing News Search API Results

Tags: parsing, bing, bing-api

Hey i am trying to parse Bing News API Search results, using Regex but finding it real hard. Can any one tell how to extract - 1. Snippet, 2. URL and 3. Name from all the results(10 is the default number) that are returned in one response ?

This is the response that i am receiving from Bing for a query.(there are 5 results returned in this)

http://ideone.com/yd8yl

Comment: is there anyone ?? has anyone used Bing API

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a regular expression for parsing the Bing response. The response is in JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) format, and depending on your programming environment, you may use an appropriate library to parse it. Please check http://www.json.org/ if you are not familiar with what JSON is.

Comment: As an example of this, the Java API includes gson.jar in the distribution which is a Java library to decode JSON data.